# Why does wrapping a None with curly braces in my match statement make this following rust code work?

Tags: rust

I have a very simple rust program where I have a hashmap<String, Vec>
and I want to insert a new array if a key does not exist and push to the existing array if the key does exist. However, If i remove the the curly braces around the None as seen in Code 2, I get the following error. What's going on? Code 1 works as expected but I just don't understand why.

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:97:20
   |
94 | /     match get_option {
95 | |         None => map.insert(str_check, vec![String::from("inserted!")]),
   | |                 ------------------------------------------------------ this is found to be of type `Option<Vec<String>>`
96 | |         
97 | |         Some(v) => v.push(String::from("Chris")),
   | |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Option<Vec<String>>`, found `()`
98 | |     }
   | |_____- `match` arms have incompatible types
   |
   = note:   expected enum `Option<Vec<String>>`
           found unit type `()`
note: method `push` modifies its receiver in-place
  --> src/main.rs:97:22
   |
97 |         Some(v) => v.push(String::from("Chris")),
   |                      ^^^^ this call modifies `v` in-place

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

Code 1.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<String, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();

    map.insert(String::from("first"), Vec::new());

    let str_check = String::from("second");
    let get_option = map.get_mut(&str_check);

    match get_option {
        None => {
            map.insert(str_check, vec![String::from("inserted!")]);
        }
        Some(v) => v.push(String::from("Chris")),
    }

    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

Code 2:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<String, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();

    map.insert(String::from("first"), Vec::new());

    let str_check = String::from("second");
    let get_option = map.get_mut(&str_check);

    match get_option {
        None => map.insert(str_check, vec![String::from("inserted!")]),
        Some(v) => v.push(String::from("Chris")),
    }

    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

Comment: Just as a hint from what I guess you want to do: You could try to use the entry function which I personally prefer for readability: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9f2e5db1c43fe1cd304e72d0f28c1426

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the braces. It's actually the semicolon.

```
map.insert(key, value)
```

This is an expression which returns a value of type `Option<V>`, as seen in the [documentation for `HashMap::insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.insert).

```
{
  map.insert(key, value)
}
```

This is entirely equivalent. Macros can distinguish between the two syntactically, but semantically they're identical. It's *still* an expression which returns an `Option<V>`.

```
{
  map.insert(key, value);
}
```

*This* returns `()`. We execute an expression for its side effects and then discard the result. A trailing semicolon in a block acts as though we put a `()` afterward. So the above is shorthand for

```
{
  map.insert(key, value);
  ()
}
```

As for why you need the `()`, it's because your other branch calls [`Vec::push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.push), which returns `()`, so for your two branches to match up, they must both return `()`.